# change default grid columns in Magento catalogue

Tags: magento, product, catalog

There are so many methods out there and it's a bit confusing but what's the best way to change the default grid columns in the Magento 1.4 product catalog?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to ask...  If you want to edit the template for the grid view, edit the following app/design/frontend/default/yourtemplate/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

If you want to change how many columns are displayed, edit the following file:  app/design/frontend/default/yourtemplate/layout/catalog.xml and look for the following tags: `<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend">`